# Max Value from one table cross joined to select values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to join two tables. This is what their skeleton looks like

TABLE #1:

| ID | T1DATA1 | T1DATA2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | ... | ... |
| 47 | ... | ... |
| 48 | ... | ... |

TABLE #2:

| ID | T2D2 | T2D3 | T2D4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Black | Mohawk | 745 |
| 2 | Blue | Flat-top | 746 |
| 3 | Yellow | Hunger | 747 |

I want to get T2D2 and T2D3 and have the table have the max id from table 1 for all the rows.
It should look something like this:

Desired Result:

| END_ID | END_D2 | END_D3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | Black | Mohawk |
| 48 | Blue | Flat-top |
| 48 | Yellow | Hunger |

I think I am over thinking this problem, I have tried cross join and different select statements.

This is where I am currently:

`SELECT max(t1.id) inv_id, t2.t2d2, t2.d3 FROM t_name2 t2 CROSS JOIN t_name t1"`

There's a case statement with data from table 2, but I have tested the select statement from table 2 by itself and it is gathering the correct information. I am simply trying to copy the max id from table #1 to all the rows of the resulting table from table #2.

I have also tried something along the lines of:

`SELECT max(t1.id) inv_id, t2.t2d2 from t_name t1, t_name2 t2 where t2.t2d2 in ('Black', 'Blue')`

But it still fails to join. The syntax is incorrect and there's nothing to match both of the tables, so I am having difficulty here.

I have had success with a statement like this:

`SELECT 46, t2.t2d2 from t_name2 t2 where t2.t2d2 in ('Black', 'Blue')`
But that is a manual input. I'd rather do this all in one query, but it looks like I might have to query for the max id first and then add it in the fashion above.

I have not been able to find a similar question. (If it has already been asked feel free to redirect me.)

Thank you for taking the time to read and respond to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it, it just seems you need a sub-query, but I have a feeling you have oversimplified or missed something out.

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(t1.id) FROM t_name t1) inv_id, t2.t2d2, t2.d3
FROM t_name2 t2
```

Comment: I oversimplified the query because I knew where the issue was. The actual query is a little more complicated, but I tested the other statements to pin-point where I was going wrong. I can't believe I forgot about a sub-query, but I think my brain was just fried. Tried up-voting your answer but I do not have enough points (?) to do so. Thank you for the response! I was able to get it working with the sub query.

Comment: After looking back on some of my previous attempts: (SELECT max(id) inv_id FROM t_name) was my previous attempt at a sub-query. Would the result name being within the parenthesis be the reason why I was unable to execute the command? @dale-k

Comment: @Marco no, having an alias inside the sub-query doesn't accomplish anything, but doesn't break it either.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I realized that I was attempting the following sub-query (Select Max(t1.Id)) .... from t_name t1, t_name2 t2. That's where I was breaking syntax.